Why would a Bitbucket Mirror Hook work from Repo A but not from Repo B?
I have a Bitbucket "Mirror Hook" (found in the "hooks" section of settings). It was correctly mirroring everything from Repo A into Repo C. But now, we have to migrate Repo A to a new location, Repo B. So I move everything over to Repo B, disable all the Hooks and Webhooks in Repo A, and then set up an identical Mirror Hook from Repo B to repo C. The Web Hook requires a 'username' and 'password', and the password is generated via Http Access Token option in the Bitbucket settings.
For some reason, this new Mirror Hook is not working. I don't see branches pushed to Repo B appearing in Repo C. And its tough to troubleshoot because, unlike Bitbucket's "Webhooks", Mirror Hooks dont appear to have any 'test' functionality to test the connection, nor any logs. I also tried copying permissions of Repo A to Repo B and still no luck. Perhaps a setting in Repo C needs to be updated? Perhaps there's some logs hidden away that I can find? Can anyone help me troubleshoot why this might be happening?
